# install rcssserver

Tags: make

I'm trying to install rcssserver on Ubuntu 14.04.5, after ./configure I write the command "sudo make" and I get a bunch of lines of description and error. I can someone give me a clue on how to install it? Thanks in advance

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
Making all in libltdl
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/libltdl'
Making all in rcssbase
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase'
Making all in error
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/error'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/error'
Making all in lib
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
Making all in .
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../libltdl  -I/usr/include -W -I./src -g -O2 -MT loader.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/loader.Tpo -c -o loader.lo loader.cpp
 g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../.. -I../../libltdl -I/usr/include -W -I./src -g -O2 -MT loader.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/loader.Tpo -c loader.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/loader.o
loader.cpp: In static member function ‘static boost::filesystem::path rcss::lib::Loader::stripDirName(const boost::filesystem::path&)’:
loader.cpp:158:38: error: conversion from ‘boost::filesystem::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
     std::string rval = filename.leaf();
                                      ^
make[4]: *** [loader.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase/lib'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1/rcssbase'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsan/Downloads/rcss-sf/rcssbase-12.1.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: At a guess, the software you are trying to build (which appears to be 10 years old) is incompatible with the version of the boost libraries on your system. Have you tried building one of the newer releases?

Comment: the newer versions are available but I face the same problems with them too!....

Comment: Are you sure it is the same problem? 12.1.1 appears to use the deprecated boost filesystem accessor `leaf()` whereas for example (the latest) `15.3.0` does not. See for example [Boost Filesystem Deprecated Features](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/deprecated.html)